# Convert tpl template to twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I have file tpl in drupal 7 like this:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php { print $attributes; } ?>>
    <?php 
    $content_section = '<div class="'.$container_class.'">';
    foreach($columns as $key => $column) {
      $content_section .= render($column);
    }
    $content_section .='</div>';
    if(isset($customHTML)){
      $customHTML = str_replace('[content]', $content_section, $customHTML);
      print $customHTML;
    }
    else {
      print $content_section;
    }?>
</div>
```

I want convert two twig template. But i have problem with function **render**() and **str_replace**(). I know in twig have function [replace](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html). But don't know how to convert to twig.

Comment: The render function is run whether you print a render array in twig (`{{ content }}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 8 you can use the drupal `|render` twig filter:

```
{{ myvar|render }}
```

Replace might be used as:

```
{% set customHTML = customHTML|replace({'[content]': content_section}) %}
```

having the variables all ready.

To convert your whole template to twig [have a look at loops](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation), also.

Answer (score 2):

For render, you can do something like

```
{{ variable|render }}
```

For more information on converting .tpl to twig, kindly check out "[Drupal Twig conversion instructions (tpl.php to html.twig)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/drupal-twig-conversion-instructions-tplphp-to-htmltwig)".

Answer (score 0):

Same with @Alex and @Suresh R

```
{{ myvar|render }}
```

you can follow [document](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates) see more filter in drupal 8. Note if variable customHtml have tag html. You need use filter **raw** to print it.

```
{{ myvar|raw }}
```